# How to find unused images from CQ DAM

Tags: aem

Is there a way to find to unused assets from CQ DAM? Currently our CQ instance has accumulated huge amount of assets and at least 25% is not being used as of now. Our CQ instance is running on windows (5.6). Is there a cleaner way to do the same?

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following XPATH query to get all assets:

```
/jcr:root/content/dam//*[@jcr:primaryType='dam:Asset']
```

Using QueryManger you may get list of asset nodes:

```
Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();
QueryManager qm = workspace.getQueryManager();
Query query = qm.createQuery(xpathQuery, Query.XPATH);
QueryResult queryResult = query.execute();
result = queryResult.getNodes();
```

Next you need to get path of every asset and verify is it used:

```
while(result.hasNext()) {
    Node assetNode = result.nextNode();
    String assetPath = assetNode.getPath();
}
```

To verify is it asset used you need again run xpath :

```
/jcr:root/content/mywebsite//*[@fileReference='putAssetPathHere']
```

Now `result.hasNext() == true` means asset is used

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.  The query "/jcr:root/content/dam//*[@fileReference='putAssetPathHere']" is alway returning me false. After replacing the proper asset path.

Comment: @kallada sorry, i have inserted wrong path, you need to use necessary pass of yours wesite /jcr:root/content/mywebsite//*[@fileReference='putAssetPathHere'], or you may use just /jcr:root//*[@fileReference='putAssetPathHere'], but it will be long running query

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use [ReferenceSearch](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/v5_2/cq-wcm-javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/commons/ReferenceSearch.html)

```
for (String path : paths) {
    if (resourceResolver.getResource(path) != null) {
        Map<String, ReferenceSearch.Info> searchResult = referenceSearch.search(resourceResolver, path);

        if (searchResult.isEmpty()) {
            //path is unused asset
        }

        //get used pages
        for (Map.Entry<String, ReferenceSearch.Info> info : searchResult.entrySet()) {
            info.getKey();//will return page path
        }

        //get used properties paths
        for (Map.Entry<String, ReferenceSearch.Info> info : searchResult.entrySet()) {
            for (String prop : info.getValue().getProperties()) {
                //prop is property path
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me following code worked.
help link : http://wemcode.wemblog.com/get_asset_reference_in_page

```
String damPath = "/content/dam/geometrixx/offices/basel kitchen.jpg";

   for (ReferenceSearch.Info info: new ReferenceSearch().search(resourceResolver, damPath).values()) {

  for (String p: info.getProperties()) {

           out.println("Path is "+info.getPage().getPath());

       }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.